# get server date and time through hidden field

Tags: php

```
<TD> <Li id="ll" >
    <label class="description" for="element_10">Mobile No </label>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" size="15" value=  />
    </div> 
    </Li></TD>
```

How can I get the system date and time through the hidden field and to insert into a MySQL database?

Comment: if it is hidden who will be able to enter into it. If you are generating it, why put it into the html at all?

Comment: You can use `NOW()` at MySQL, which will insert current timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use php? if so

```
         <input type="hidden" size="15" name="date" value=<?=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>  />
```

and then after Form posted or you can use ajax you can get the value like this;

```
         <?php $date=$_REQUEST['date']; ?>
```

And then you should Insert to your mysql table and this is like this

```
         $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO date_table(date) VALUES($date)");
```

ok now you inserted it. I Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: First question seems strange, the question is tagged `php`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d g:i a");// current date
$currentTime = time($todayDate); //Change date into time
$entrytime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$currentTime);

<TD> <Li id="ll" >
    <label class="description" for="element_10">Mobile No </label>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" size="15" name="date" value="<?=$entrytime?>"  />
    </div> 
    </Li></TD>
```

Comment: `input` needs a `name` attribute

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you insert `NOW()` to database:

```
 INSERT INTO date_table(date) VALUES('NOW()')
```

If you consist post the time to server by a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" size="15" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>" />
```